# Creating a Square by lines and through user input in p5.js

Tags: javascript, processing, drawing, draw, p5.js

I am learning user input through mouse in p5.js and i want to create a square by 4 line method on 4 different clicks , 1 click for each line and the last click completing the square.
below code is for 2 lines but the are both running at the same time and i cannot understand the if command to separately run them .

```js
function setup() {
    createCanvas(400, 400);
    background(220);
}

function draw() {  
}

function mousePressed()
{
    line(width/20,height/40,mouseX,mouseY);
    line(pmouseX,pmouseY,mouseX,mouseY);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've to store the points to a list. If the list contains 4 elements and the mouse is clicked again, clear the list:

```js
var pts = [];
function mousePressed()
{
    if (pts.length == 4) {
        pts = [];
    }
    pts.push([mouseX, mouseY])
}
```

Do all the drawing continuously in [`draw()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/draw).  Clear the background. Draw the liens between the points ins a loop. If the number of point is 4, the draw a line from the last point to the 1st point.
Additionally you can draw a "rubber" line from the last point to the current mouse position, if there is at least 1 point in the list:

```js
function draw() {  
      background(220);

      // draw the lines between the points
      for (var i=0; i < pts.length-1; ++i) {
          line(pts[i][0], pts[i][1], pts[i+1][0], pts[i+1][1]);
      }

      var close = pts.length == 4;
      if (close) {
          // draw line from 1st point to at point
          line(pts[pts.length-1][0], pts[pts.length-1][1], pts[0][0], pts[0][1]); 
      }
      else if (pts.length > 0) {
          // draw a rubber line from last point to the mouse
          line(pts[pts.length-1][0], pts[pts.length-1][1], mouseX,mouseY); 
      }
}
```

See the example

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

var pts = [];
function mousePressed()
{
    if (pts.length == 4) {
        pts = [];
    }
    pts.push([mouseX, mouseY])
}

function draw() {  
      background(220);

      // draw the lines between the points
      for (var i=0; i < pts.length-1; ++i) {
          line(pts[i][0], pts[i][1], pts[i+1][0], pts[i+1][1]);
      }

      var close = pts.length == 4;
      if (close) {
          // draw line from 1st point to at point
          line(pts[pts.length-1][0], pts[pts.length-1][1], pts[0][0], pts[0][1]); 
      }
      else if (pts.length > 0) {
          // draw a rubber line from last point to the mouse
          line(pts[pts.length-1][0], pts[pts.length-1][1], mouseX,mouseY); 
      }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply,  i understand what you did ( i think) but i don't really understand the push function and pts[pts.length-1][0], pts[pts.length-1][1], what does [0] and [1] mean. thank you

Comment: i think push function is storing the original values and [0] means X and [1] Means Y,

Comment: @SilentHG This is  basic javascript. You should know that, before you start such a task or a ask a question. Read about [JavaScript Arrays](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/javascript-tutorial/javascript-arrays.php). `a.push(x)` adds the element `x` to the array `a`. In this case the element itself is an array (`[mouseX, mouseY]`). `a[i]` is the index operator and returns the `i`th element of the array `a`. If there is an array in an array, then `pts[i][j]` returns the coordinate `j` from the `i`th element of `pts`.